# How come outline is visible on one but not the other?

Tags: css

Not visible here: curtains open by themselves.

Not visible: outline: 1px solid red; https://jsfiddle.net/3sz47bq0/1/

How would I have the 1px line be visible here?

```
.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image]

But that 1px line is visible here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdzcj6og/1/

The curtains don’t auto open here.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because in your `.curtain` class you have the property `overflow: hidden;`. If you remove it then the outline will show.

```css
.curtain {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 3.2px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

Comment: But overflow: hidden; is needed, and it is used in the other code here: https://jsfiddle.net/pdzcj6og/1/